# Parameterize Post Request payload using Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have below post request in Rest Assured code :

I want to parameterize it. Please suggest.

```
       given().contentType(JSON).with()
          .body("\"id\":"123",\"email\":\"abv@gmail.com\"}").expect().body("status",            
        notNullValue()).when().post("https://localhost:8080/product/create.json");
```

Parameters

id, email.

When I declared String variables id,email and try passing in body() its not working.

Not working code:

```
 String id="123";
 String email=abc@gmail.com;

 given().contentType(JSON).with()
  .body("\"id\":id,\"email\":email}").expect().body("status",              
   notNullValue()).when().post("https://localhost:8080/product/create.json");
```

Comment: Probably not important but an opening curly brace seems to be missing at the beginning of your body.

Comment: sorry i missed to provide it. but still im getting issue.

Answer (score 3):

In body we need to give the exact string like :

```
"{\"id\":" + id + ",\"email\":" + email + "}"
```

This should work. But this is not the best approach. You should consider creating a class with 2 fields( id and email ), and as body to the request you should add the json-serialised body of the object.

```
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(id, email);
String loginAsString = Util.toJson(loginRequest);
given().contentType(JSON).with()
   .body(loginAsString)...
```

Try this way.
Hope it helps.

Comment: how to support or to handle nested parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a [POJO](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#serialization) you can also use a [HashMap](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#create-json-from-a-hashmap):

```
given().
        contentType(JSON).
        body(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("name", "John Doe");
            put("address", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("street", "Some street");
                put("areaCode", 21223);
            }});
        }}).
when().
        post("https://localhost:8080/product/create.json")
then().
        body("status",  notNullValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending a string with a large number of the parameter can become tedious and updating a string having n number of parameters may become time-consuming. Hence, it is always recommended to send an object in body method.

I would advise you to go through my step by step tutorial on Rest Assured:

[Automating POST Request using Rest Assured](https://restservicestesting.blogspot.in/2016/10/automating-post-request-using-rest_19.html)

Have a look at below example

```
public class Posts {

public String id;
public String title;
public String author;

public void setId (String id) {

this.id = id;
}

public void setTitle (String title) {

this.title = title;
}

public void setAuthor (String author) {

this.author = author;

}

public String getId () {

return id;

}

public String getTitle () {

return title;
}

public String getAuthor () {

return author;
}

}
```

In the above Post class, we have created getter and setter methods of the parameters that we need to pass to the body method.

Now we will send the POST request

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import com.restapiclass.Posts;

public class PostRequestTest {


@BeforeClass
public void setBaseUri () {

RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:3000";
}


@Test
public void sendPostObject () {

Posts post = new Posts();
post.setId ("3");
post.setTitle ("Hello India");
post.setAuthor ("StaffWriter");

given().body (post)
.when ()
.contentType (ContentType.JSON)
.post ("/posts");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes in your code. When using Rest Assured and want to pass a variable inside the body("...."), the syntax is

`"{\"id\": \""+id+"\", \"email\": \""+email+"\"}";`

parameters inside the body of Rest Assured(`"+id+"` & `"+email+"`) should be written inside double-quotes.

Comment: Please explain *how* this solves the problem. What does it improve or fix? StackOverflow puts posts without explanations on the Low Quality Posts queue for review to see if they should be deleted and you can fix that and editing your answers to be more descriptive. https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/